# How to split this using Regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this type of string

```
"Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"
```

I want to get like this

```
["Cat,Wheat,Com,Ogl,oyher,Face,Express,Star"]
```

Basically split at "," and "/"

I tried using split function but for that I had to use double forloop  not so efficient

I did some research and came across regex

```
re.split('\W+',string , 1)
```

but this is not working ,what should I add to filter

Comment: I think your expected output is incorrect.

Comment: Are you really trying to get a single string in a list like `"Cat,Wheat,Com,Ogl,oyher,Face,Express,Star"` Or do you want a list of individual items like `['Cat', 'Wheat'...]`

Comment: Why do you limit it to one split? Use `re.split('\W+', data)` and you'll get `['Cat', 'Wheat', 'Com', 'Ogl', 'oyher', 'Face', 'Express', 'Star', '']`. This can be transformed to the expected result quite easy (if you really want the result you showed in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear why you are adding the maxsplit argument of `1` to your `split()` – that prevents it from splitting everything you want.

Without it you get:

```
> import re
> s = "Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"
> re.split(r'\W+', s)
['Cat', 'Wheat', 'Com', 'Ogl', 'oyher', 'Face', 'Express', 'Star', '']
```

That's pretty close expect for the soul-crushing empty at the end. You can filter that out, but you might be happier with `re.findall()` to match what you want rather than splitting what you don't:

```
> import re
> s = "Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"
> re.findall(r'\w+', s)
['Cat', 'Wheat', 'Com', 'Ogl', 'oyher', 'Face', 'Express', 'Star']
```

To get a single comma-separated string (if that's what you want) you can join:

```
> import re
> s = "Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"
> ",".join(re.findall(r'\w+', s))
'Cat,Wheat,Com,Ogl,oyher,Face,Express,Star'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> import re

>> data = "Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"

>> words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", data)

>> print(words)
['Cat', 'Wheat', 'Com', 'Ogl', 'oyher', 'Face', 'Express', 'Star']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after timing, you are probably better of with a series of Python string manipulations:

```
def multisplit(s, splits=('/', ','), base_split=' '):
    for split in splits:
        s = s.replace(split, base_split)
    return s.split() if not base_split.split() else list(filter(bool, s.split(base_split))
```

or, even faster (for slightly larger inputs):

```
def multisplit2(s, splits=('/', ','), base_split=' '):
    s = functools.reduce(lambda t, r: t.replace(s, base_split), splits, s)
    return s.split() if not base_split.split() else list(filter(bool, s.split(base_split))
```

A quick comparison with `re`-based solutions indicate a 5x to 10x speed up for the proposed approach:

```
import re


def re_findall(s):
    return re.findall(r"[\w']+", s)

def re_split(s):
    return list(filter(bool, re.split('\W+', s)))


s = "Cat/Wheat , Com, Ogl/oyher Face Express/Star,"
print(re_findall(s))
print(re_split(s))
print(multisplit(s))
# ['Cat', 'Wheat', 'Com', 'Ogl', 'oyher', 'Face', 'Express', 'Star']

%timeit re_findall(s)
# 2.54 µs ± 9.14 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit re_split(s)
# 3.05 µs ± 6.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit multisplit(s)
# 631 ns ± 10.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit multisplit2(s)
# 908 ns ± 12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit re_findall(s * 1000)
# 1.55 ms ± 5.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit re_split(s * 1000)
# 1.96 ms ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit multisplit(s * 1000)
# 222 µs ± 7.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit multisplit2(s * 1000)
# 149 µs ± 1.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```